# How to execute Shell Commands with Java and print the output directly while executing the command

Tags: java

How do I execute Shell Commands with Java?

At the same time, I print the output directly while executing the command, for example, the ping command, tests the connection with a specific location and gives me the response time at each node during the connection, and it gives me a set of lines at separate intervals. I want to print these lines as soon as it comes back, how do I do that?

Comment: I'm not in an ideal situation trying to simplify the code right now): @Abra

Comment: You might want to wait to ask until you *are* in an ideal time to improve the question. These improvements can make your question much easier to answer, helping both you and the site.

Comment: Well I will try to simplify the example (:@HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ping", "localhost");
pb.inheritIO();
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    int exitStatus = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println(exitStatus);
}
catch (InterruptedException | IOException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

I believe the above does what you want and I would say that the code is a lot simpler.

Refer to the *javadoc* for class `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Great, I will try it out, thanks